# C++ using enumerations with for loops to fill a float Array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, enumerator

My exercise is:

> Write a program that gets the user's choice of color strength and transparency. Use a single enumeration for the colors and transparency - `RED`, `GREEN`, `BLUE`, `ALPHA`. Use a `for` loop that utilizes the enumeration set to iterate from `RED` up to `ALPHA` inclusive. Inside the `for` loop get the user to enter a value for each enumerated constant(i.e. a value for red, a value for blue, etc.) the values should be between `0.0` and `1.0` and stored in an array.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum Difficulty
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    ALPHA

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char cColours[10][14] = { "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "ALPHA" };

    float fArray[4];
    int icounter = 0;

    while (icounter != 5)
    {

        std::cout << "For colour " << cColours[icounter] << " please enter a number ranging from 0.0 - 1.0 " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "press 10 to exit " << std::endl;


        for (int i = RED; i = ALPHA; i++)
        std::cin >> fArray[i];
        ++icounter;

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No way that for loop does what you think it does...

Comment: hahaha, well they want me to use the enumerators in the loop so im a little confused how to implement it , any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: or maybe im reading the question wrong =/

Comment: Your for loop is a definite error. It is 100% wrong. It has no "condition" (`i=ALPHA` is an assignment)

Comment: i thought so i havnt learnt much on enumerators, do you understand the question by any chance and how it can be fixed ?

Comment: What question are you asking? Do you want us to do your assignment for you?

Comment: Please read the SO guidelines, in particular those concerning a minimal example. If you did that, I'm pretty sure it would have dawned on you what your error is.

Comment: i have no idea what you just said buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments you want to get one color mix (r,g,b,a). You use nested arrays for nothing.

So one possible code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

enum ColorChannels {RED = 0, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA, ALL_CHANNELS};
/*Every enumeration gives values to its elements. In default the first element is zero,
I illustrated this here. So ALL_CHANNELS (or difficulty if you want is equal with four,
which is the number of all channels - this will be useful in loop*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     std::string names[ALL_CHANNELS];
     names[RED] = "RED"; //this is same to names[0]
     names[1] = "GREEN";
     names[BLUE] = "BLUE";
     names[3] = "ALPHA";
     /*I'm not sure if char sequences work. If work, use it. I prefer more the strings*/
     float colorArray[ALL_CHANNELS];

     for (int i = 0; i < ALL_CHANNELS; i++)
     {
          std::cout << "Enter " << names[i] << " value between 0.0 and 1.0: ";
          //For instance "Enter RED value between 0.0 and 1.0: "

          //and NOW your read one parameter. You made a nested loop for nothing
          std::cin >> colorArray[i];
          std::cout << "\n"; //for a new line
     }
     // all elements read

     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Try to do some improvements for exercise, like writing colors back; writing out if it is more likely red, blue or green; reading more colors; etc.

Comment: awesome thanks alot =) , so you used separate char strings instead of a 2d array right ? , std::string names[ALL_CHANNELS];  what does that piece of code do ?

Comment: Tomas Munro: First question: yes. Second question: std::string is a type from std, it's like you write int or char. So you create a variable of type std::string. You create array, which has 4 elements, because the ALL_CHANNELS is equal with 4 in the enumeration(every identifier in enumameration has a value). Of course you can simply write [4], but imagine that you extend the enumeration. In this case the last element always will be equal with the number of precedent elements, if the first is 0.

Comment: Tomas Munro: Also, please notice the difference between assignment '=' and equality '=='

Comment: @Tomas Munro: I never used them, but this might help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/